# Couldn't load model: Invalid argument: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'Prod' with these attrs

Tags: ios, tensorflow

I'm trying to load the faster_rcnn_resnet101_coco model from the [Tensorflow Object Detection model zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md) onto the iOS camera example. I've successfully built the tensorflow (r.14) library from bazel for iOS.  However, when running, I can't get pass error:

```
2017-10-30 18:00:28.307769: E [path]/tensorflow_utils.mm:209] Could not create TensorFlow Graph: Invalid argument: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'Prod' with these attrs.  Registered devices: [CPU], Registered kernels:
  <no registered kernels>

     [[Node: SecondStageBoxPredictor/Flatten/Prod = Prod[T=DT_INT32, Tidx=DT_INT32, keep_dims=false](SecondStageBoxPredictor/Flatten/Slice_1, SecondStageBoxPredictor/Flatten/Const)]]
2017-10-30 18:00:28.320101: F [path]CameraExampleViewController.mm:495] Couldn't load model: Invalid argument: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'Prod' with these attrs.  Registered devices: [CPU], Registered kernels:
  <no registered kernels>

     [[Node: SecondStageBoxPredictor/Flatten/Prod = Prod[T=DT_INT32, Tidx=DT_INT32, keep_dims=false](SecondStageBoxPredictor/Flatten/Slice_1, SecondStageBoxPredictor/Flatten/Const)]]
```

As I understand it, I need to include the "Prod" ops when building the tensorflow library in "ops_to_register.h".  However, this still fails, and when I look at the "tf_ops_files.txt" to see which ops are registered, I'm not really sure which kernel library the "Prod" op belongs to.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run after recreating the "op_to_register.h" file using

```
bazel build tensorflow/python/tools:print_selective_registration_header 
  bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/tools/print_selective_registration_header \
    --graphs=path/to/graph.pb > ops_to_register.h
```

The kernel missing that is associated with the "Prod" op turns out to be part of "reduction_prod_op.cc".